# One model to different tables

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have two similar tables and two similar models except for the name of the teables. In the controller I call two different models in the constructor:

```
$this->load->model('sites_model', 'sites');
$this->load->model('servers_model', 'servers');
```

But I don't need to duplicate code. And I found a solution to this problem:

```
class My_Model extends CI_Model 
{
    protected $table = NULL;

    public function __construct($table = '')
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->table = $table;
    }
}
```

This model is stored in application/core/MY_Model.php.
But I don't understand how I call the model with the correct table to me. Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MY_Model.php:

```
public function set_table($table = '')
{
    $this->table = $table;
}
```

Create a new model 'blank_model.php' with just:

```
class Blank_model extends MY_Model
{
   public function __construct()
   {
       parent::__construct();
   }
}
```

Then from you controller:

```
$this->load->model('blank_model');
$this->blank_model->set_table('Name of table');
```

Comment: Okay, but how it will look in the controller?

Comment: `$this->load->model('Name of model');`

Comment: I mean, how can I call the model with the desired table (in the controller).

Comment: So, you have your 2 models and My_model, in both of your 2 models that are extending MY_model have the constructor above that is titled 'In other models'

Comment: But my goal is to have a single model.

Comment: MY_model isn't designed to be accessed directly. I'll change my answer to accommodate for this. However, there is nothing wrong with having multiple models that just extend the base model.

Comment: I know, but I've got two exactly the same model, with the exception of the table names. I think it's not very good

Comment: No, you put all of that logic in MY_Model and then you just have a new model that sets the table...all of the functionality will still be available...it's just standard abstraction. I updated my answer for you :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to pass argument to model constructor that I know of. But you can add method to model to update table you want to access.

```
// method goes into MY_Model.php
public function set_table($table_name)
{
    $this->table = $table_name;
}
```

Then from controller you can do like:

```
$this->model->set_table('my_table');
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll suggest a **slight modification** in your DB structure. It'll make it more **flexible** and code repetition can be avoided here. Checkout the below **DB Structure**,

```
actual_table:

id  |  column1  |  column2  |  column3  |  column4  |  type_id
1   |  value11  |  value12  |  value13  |  value14  |  1            # sites
2   |  value21  |  value22  |  value23  |  value24  |  2            # servers
3   |  value31  |  value32  |  value33  |  value34  |  1            # sites


type_table:

id  |  name
1   |  sites
2   |  servers
```

Since your structure is same for both of the tables, there is unnecessary **db and code duplication**. Instead create one table which will consist of the **types** (viz. sites, servers) and create one table for **sites/servers** adding a new column **`type_id`** which would be a **Foreign Key** to the **`type_table`**

It's not the exact answer to your question but a **better alternative**.

Comment: Thank you, I was not even thinking in this direction.

Comment: Happy to help. It'll change your code and DB a bit, but it'll relax you in future I bet.